# Not able to modify and configure instance variables from within my init method but still in same class. Python Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I am writing a quick program for a class project.  I am fairly new to tkinter and most problems I have been able to find answers for.  However, now I am stuck.  I want to disable buttons on my widget when a new window pops and then reactivate them when the windows close.  Pretty simple concept, and from what I read should be easy to do.  However, I am still learning class structures and struggling with the idea of object-oriented programming.  I set up my buttons in the init method for the class on my main window.

Then I defined the button command method inside the same class.  Everything works great, but when I try to disable the buttons from a config method defined in the same class, the method doesn't recognize the button variables I created.  I have a feeling this is because they are only instance variables and have no memory outside the instance.  So I need to know how to initialize the buttons and then access their[Brief look at my code and how things are set-up currently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBC3V.png) variables to force action on them.

I have tried moving them to a class Variable, but that doesn't set the buttons up.  I have also tried changing or removing prefixes (didn't expect it to work and it didn't)  I have tried everything I have found online, but I am stuck. (I commented out the disable options for now until I get it to work)  full code available on github https://github.com/mgentile77/DnD5e.git

```
class Horde_Maker:
#Main Window class all other windows come from here
def __init__(self,root):
    #Initializes the main window and starts program
    self.app = root
    #This sections creates window size and location on pop up 
    width = 300
    height = 200
    screen_wid = root.winfo_screenwidth()
    screen_hei = root.winfo_screenheight()
    x = (screen_wid/2) - (width/2)
    y = (screen_hei/2) - (height/2)
    self.app.title("Horde Maker")
    self.app.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (width, height, x, y))
    self.app.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.disable_Xclose)
    #Begins layout of window widgets
    self.set_up()
    
def set_up(self):
    #sets up window widgets for this class    
    self.frame_header = ttk.Frame()#Frame for image
    self.frame_header.pack()
    
    self.frame_start = ttk.Frame()#Frame for start welcome and instructions
    self.frame_start.pack()
    ttk.Label(self.frame_start, text = "Welcome To The").pack()
    ttk.Label(self.frame_start, text = "HORDE MAKER").pack()
    ttk.Label(self.frame_start, text = "Choose Your Path").pack()
    
    self.frame_buttons = ttk.Frame()#Frame for buttons and pops buttons
    self.frame_buttons.pack()
    but_horde = ttk.Button(self.frame_buttons, text = "Horde Maker", command = self.hordebutton)
    but_horde.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
    
    but_char = ttk.Button(self.frame_buttons, text = "Character Builder", command = self.characterbutton)
    but_char.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
    ttk.Button(self.frame_buttons, text = 'Exit', command = lambda : exit()).grid(row = 1, column = 0, columnspan = 2)

#Begins Class methods used in functions of of buttons
def hordebutton(self):#opens Horde window
    self.hord_button = Horde()
    # self.disable_but()
    
def characterbutton(self):#opens Character Window
    self.char_button = Character()
    # self.disable_but()

#Creates parent class instructions for other windows    
def clear_frame(self,frame):#Destroys child window on exit 
    for widgets in frame.winfo_children():
        widgets.destroy() 

def disable_Xclose(self):#prevents closing the window by using corner X
    pass

# @staticmethod
# def disable_but():
#     but_horde.config(state = DISABLED)
#     but_char.config(state = DISABLED)

# @staticmethod
# def enable_but():
#     but_horde.config(state = NORMAL)
#     but_char.config(state = NORMAL)
```

Comment: Show code and other textual information as properly formatted text in the question, not as comment, image or external link.

Comment: got it sort of. this is the main class which I am having issues with.  thanks for the help.

Comment: (1) Fix the indentation of the shown code. (2) `but_horde` and `but_char` are **local** variables (no `self.` prepended), so they cease to exist when the function is left.

Comment: Right.  The answer is to use `self.but_horde` and `self.but_char`, so they stick around.

Comment: I did try that, in fact that was the original set-up.  That is what led me down the path to what I have now.  I have set it up and tested it in a much simpler form (no class just basic tkinter), and everything worked like it should, but as soon as it put it in the class it stops working, and the only thing I can think of is that something is happening to instance variable.

Comment: That disabled the buttons but now I can't get a call to other method showed from another window to enable the buttons upon closing the window    def leave1(self):#exits window
        self.Horde_Maker.enable_but()
        self.new_win1.destroy()

Answer (score 1):

You need to use instance variables instead of local variables if those buttons are accessed outside the function where they are created.

Also *static method* of a class cannot access instance variables of that class.  Use normal class method instead.

To access those instance variables from *other class*, you can pass the instance of the class to *other class*.

```py
class Horde_Maker:
    ...

    def set_up(self):
        ...
        # use instance variables instead
        self.but_horde = ttk.Button(self.frame_buttons, text="Horde Maker", command=self.hordebutton)
        self.but_horde.grid(row=0, column=0)

        self.but_char = ttk.Button(self.frame_buttons, text="Character Builder", command=self.characterbutton)
        self.but_char.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
        ...

    def hordebutton(self):#opens Horde window
        self.disable_but()
        self.hord_button = Horde(self)  # pass instance to class Horde

    def characterbutton(self):#opens Character Window
        self.disable_but()
        self.char_button = Character(self) # pass instance to class Character

    ...

    # change to normal class method
    def disable_but(self):
        self.but_horde.config(state=DISABLED)
        self.but_char.config(state=DISABLED)

    def enable_but(self):
        self.but_horde.config(state=NORMAL)
        self.but_horde.config(state=NORMAL)

class Character(Horde_Maker):
    ...

    def __init__(self, app):
        self.app = app
        ...

    ...

    def leave2(self):
        self.app.enable_but()
        ...

    ...

class Horde(Horde_Maker):
    def __init__(self, app):
        self.app = app
        ...

    def leave1(self):
        self.app.enable_but()
        ...

    ...
```

Comment: I tried this suggestion, but because my hierarchy was already a mess, it still didn't provide the desired results.  However, it did help me realize that the error was in my child classes and they were not set up correctly to be a child class.  I re-organized and got everything going the way I wanted.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, everyone, for the assistance.  It did help me discover the root cause of my mistake.  It was how I organized my classes and attempted to create a new hierarchy chain.  I tried to create my own parent class and open new windows from within their own child class.  This means I was passing objects to my objects that were calling other objects to do the work and returning the results to my object to return the result to another one of my objects.  I should have realized that my classes were child classes from the tk parent class, and new init statements needed to be passed to the parent tk classes.  Once I reorganized my classes to follow this hierarchy, everything worked perfectly, and I gained the functionality I wanted for my program.  I still have a lot to learn, but I feel confident that I am beginning to catch on.  Please let me know what you think of this explanation.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).